# are there any XDebug alternatives for debugging PHP?

Tags: php, windows-vista, debugging, xdebug

I'm using Vista and need to debug PHP, XDebug crashes in Vista, I tried several suggestions but nothing works.

Are there there any other alternative to XDebug that works on Vista and with Eclipse PDT. Easy to install is a plus :-)

Edit: also I have Ubuntu in other PC, so any debugger for Ubuntu will work too. In the package list is a XDebug version but it's very outdated.

Answer (score 2):

I always liked [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/features#debug) for debugging amongst other things.

You can also download the zend debugger individually as an eclipse plugin from http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt

Answer (score 0):

You can, in Ubuntu always get the latest stable Xdebug with:

```
sudo pecl install Xdebug
```

You may also need to install the `build-essential` on Ubuntu if you've not already done it.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: sorry I ask this, but I'm new in Ubuntu. What is build-essential?

I have XAMPP and Eclipse PDT installed and configured correctly in Ubuntu

Comment: NP, its the compiler and other tools to be able to install some things from source. If you don't have it, it would likely just prompt you to go install it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How does it crash? Is it when you are trying to open the cachegrind files? I did find Kcachegrind (on KDE) to be much more stable to Wincachegrind.. But thats only if its the profiling that crashes..

Personally, I'd be using Ubuntu on the other machine or on a virtual machine to develop and debug.

Comment: hi, I'm actually using Ubuntu in a virtual machine (vmware) for that objective, I installed it just last week and I don't have it completely configured yet. Xdebug crashes in Vista not Ubuntu, when I start apache and go to localhost, apache crashes. If Xdebug is disabled, Apache works just fine.